# Basic SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the basicness of this query, but I need a bit of help learning here :)

This is a database for a Hotel.

Here are my tables:

- Hotel (**hotelNo**, hotelName, city)
- Room (**roomNo**, **hotelNo**, type, price)
- Booking (**hotelNo**, **guestNo**, **dateFrom**, dateTo, roomNo)
- Guest (**guestNo**, guestName, guestAddress)

Where the bolded are the primary keys. I realise it isn't the best design to have a concatenated primary key for Bookings, but that is the way it is here.

I need a query for the following:

How many different guests have made a booking for August?

Comment: what are the queries you tried so far, if any? It does not look like you tried anything?

Comment: Don't mind the composite primary key.. do mind the inconsistent use of 'ID' and 'No' however, especially on hotel and room.

Comment: That was my mistake, Arth. They are all No. I used ID on the first few out of habit.

@TheChaos,

I am not sure how to use joins... so I am stumped from the beginning.. I can do it if I can get the two tables joined properly

Comment: Ah ok, as long as they are all consistent now, please update the question.

Comment: Do you just want it for total guests regardless of hotel/room, and also do you just want the count or do you want the details for the guests?

Comment: Just need a count of the unique guests at all hotels during August

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT guestno)
FROM   booking
WHERE  MONTH(datefrom) = 8
```

Comment: That will include any year, and won't include bookings that end in August but start before, or span August entirely.

Comment: This seems the easiest and simplest! Cheers mate

Comment: @Arth: Sorry, I should have specified more. I just need the bookings that have been made **for** August, as in dateFrom August.

Comment: @LukeBeacon No problem, I was working off "Just need a count of the unique guests at all hotels during August".. I'll leave my answer as is just in case you need that logic at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Make a count of the number of guests during the month of July.

Then do the same for the month of August.

Make the difference between these two values ​​and have the number of new guests that have made a booking for August.

Not a very good shape, however it is an option where you can start.

Comment: Whaaat? Why even think about the July bookings.. i think he means distinct guests.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
select guestName, guestAddress from Booking b 
inner join Guest g on b.guestNo=g.guestNo
inner join Hotel h on b.hotelNo=h.hotelID 
inner join Room r on b.roomNo=r.roomID
where b.hotelID=h.hotelID and 
MONTHNAME(dateFrom) = 'August' 
and MONTHNAME(dateTo)='August'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT guestNo)
  FROM booking
 WHERE dateTo >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08');
   AND dateFrom < CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-09');
```

This will include bookings that cover August entirely, or start or finish in August.. which I don't think the other answers cover.

I also assumed that you only wanted this for the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work for you,

```
SELECT 
       Booking.*,
       Guest.*
FROM   Guest
       JOIN Booking 
              ON Guest.guestNo = Booking
       LEFT JOIN Room 
              ON Booking.roomNo = Room.roomID
       LEFT JOIN Hotel 
              ON Room.hotelID = Hotel.hotelID
WHERE
       MONTH(datefrom) = '8'
```

There is one more suggestion on booking table composite key. 
Composite key for Booking table should be **guestNo, roomNo, hotelNo, dateFrom**

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres 15

/*6.15 How many different guests have made bookings for August?*/

```sql
select 
    count(distinct guestno) as "Number of different guests have made bookings for August"
from 
    booking
where 
    (extract (month from (datefrom)) >= 8 and extract (month from (dateto)) <=8 ) or 
    (extract (month from (datefrom)) <= 8 and extract (month from (dateto)) >=8 ) or
    (extract (month from (datefrom)) = 8) or 
    (extract (month from (dateto)) = 8)
;
```